# Crank and Bottom Brackets Compatibility for Shimano GRX

Tags: shimano, crankset, bottom-bracket

I want to get myself a GRX810 2× but instead of buying the recommended (by Shimano) bottom brackets (SM-BBR60 or SM-BB72-41B Pressfit Hollowtech II) I would like to go with either the Token TF24 or the Token Ninja TF37. I am not sure if they are compatible with the GRX810 Group.

Could anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I can see on the Token page, you need to select a BB that matches the crank axle diameter (24mm for Shimano) and the frame bearing cup standard your frame has. The Token web site has a nice filter that lets you select crank and BB cup types so I'd let that guide you initially.

[This](https://www.bikeradar.com/advice/buyers-guides/the-complete-guide-to-bottom-bracket-standards/) is about the most informative page I've found on the myriad of BB standards.

By the way, the TF24 appears to be natively designed for 24mm axles but the TF37 uses adapters for different axle diameters. Go with the 24mm axle specific design if you can. I think that if you have a frame designed for a BB for 30mm axles you may have to get a TF37 and use the adapters.

Comment: I have found out that my frame has e BB386EVO pressfit 86.5x46mm BB shell. I have found this one Rotor Road Press Fit 4624 BB386 EVO Bottom Bracket that seems to fit. Thank you for telling me what to look for!